# How to install Whatsapp on Android 1.6

Tags: cyanogenmod, whatsapp-messenger, htc-dream, 1.6-donut

I am interested in installing Whatsapp on Android 1.6 (Cyanogenmod 4.2) on a rooted HTC Dream G1. Is there any way to install it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [whatsapp](http://www.whatsapp.com/android/) site, the minimum requirements are Android 2.1, so even if you managed to find the APK and side-load it onto the G1 running 1.6, it probably will not work.

Stable releases of CyanogenMod 5 (Android 2.1) and 6 (Android 2.2) are both [available](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Dream%3aInstalling_CyanogenMod_5+) for the G1.  You can install Whatsapp if you upgrade to CM 5/6.

Comment: I already tried out CyanogenMod 5 but its too slow and hangs a lot. So, I shifted back to CyanogenMod 4. I was just curious if there was a work around for Android 1.6